# How to run a test plan multiple time with successive increasing concurrency

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan. Set some users there. How can I run this test plan multiple times consequently with 1x load, 5x load, 10x load without change the test plan and  keep all the logs with unique log name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use property for Thread Group settings, for example

Put Thread Group's `Number of Threads` value as `${__P(threadNum,1)}`

Call the jmx with different property value `-JthreadNum=1`, `-JthreadNum=5`, `-JthreadNum=10`

That way you will achieve different load with same test plan